# Meaning of heap memory addresses in GC logs using -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC?

Tags: java, memory, logging, garbage-collection, jvm

The Java [heap is divided into regions known as generations](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/java-garbage-collection-distilled.html), e.g. *new generation*, which may be further divided, e.g. *eden space*. Using the `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC` JVM option, **three memory addresses for each heap region are printed in the GC logs** in the form `[A, B, C)`, where `A`, `B` and `C` are memory addresses, e.g.:

```
eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x000000073ae00000, 0x000000076e140000, 0x000000076e140000)
```

**What is the meaning of these memory addresses?**

I have searched the web but am unable to find any explanation of this part of the GC logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A (bottom)` - lower address of the reserved memory region;
`B (top)` - current pointer to the top of the allocated area;
`C (end)` - upper bound of the reserved memory region.

Here are the relevant references to the source code.

[space.hpp:](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/0499e4a89c76/src/share/vm/memory/space.hpp#l513)

```
// Size computations: sizes in bytes.
size_t capacity() const        { return byte_size(bottom(), end()); }
size_t used() const            { return byte_size(bottom(), top()); }
size_t free() const            { return byte_size(top(),    end()); }
```

[space.cpp:](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/0499e4a89c76/src/share/vm/memory/space.cpp#l515)

```
void ContiguousSpace::print_on(outputStream* st) const {
  print_short_on(st);
  st->print_cr(" [" INTPTR_FORMAT ", " INTPTR_FORMAT ", " INTPTR_FORMAT ")",
                bottom(), top(), end());
}
```

Comment: wrt `B (top)`, am I correct in thinking that this is meaningful because the heap region has been compacted "leftwards" during GC?

Comment: @coxjam All NewGen spaces are contiguous, which means that allocation is done "left-to-right" by a simple pointer increment. `top` is exactly this pointer. Everything below it is used area, and the area above it is free.